# How to override render_to_response method in CreateView Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, mako

I'm writing CreateView generic-view in my application and I want to override the render_to_response method.
I've tried to do the same thing with below code.

```
from edxmako.shortcuts import render_to_response as render_to_response_mako

class CreateView( generic.CreateView ):
    template_name = 'cms/templates/form_bsct.html'

    print dir(generic.CreateView)
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({'name':'jay'})
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print args
        print kwargs
        """
        Handles GET requests and instantiates a blank version of the form.
        """
        template_name = 'cms/templates/form_bsct.html'
        import os
        print os.getcwd()
        return render_to_response_mako(template_name)
```

In above code I'm trying to override the native render_to_response method with edxmako render_to_response method.
It is giving me below error.

```
    "Cant locate template for uri %r" % uri)
TopLevelLookupException: Cant locate template for uri 'cms/templates/form_bsct.html'
```

It is not getting the template. Please help me how to do that?

Comment: Well, that points to an issue with how you're configuring or calling Mako, it doesn't appear to have anything to do with "overriding render_to_response" (which you're not doing).

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the reply. I have forked openedx and they are using edxmako's render_to_response method. So does I. But CreateView calls native render_to_response and that is I think totally different than the edxmako's. help me here.